# sqlite Common table expression

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression

I was working at a project and I've been asked to rewrite this subquerie

```
SELECT c.last_name, c.first_name, i.total_avg
  FROM customer AS c
  JOIN (SELECT customer_id, AVG(total) AS total_avg
          FROM invoice
         GROUP BY customer_id) AS i
    ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id;
```

using CTE.

I don't know how to link the two tables.

Could you help me?
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the inner select, declare the subquery as a CTE:

```sql
WITH i AS (
    SELECT customer_id, AVG(total) AS total_avg
    FROM invoice
    GROUP BY customer_id
) SELECT c.last_name, c.first_name, i.total_avg
    FROM customer AS c
    JOIN i ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id;
```

See [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) for details.

Comment: Oh ok...I get! Should I put a coma before the second Select clause?  Thank you!

Comment: You mean after the closing parenthesis? No. The syntax is `WITH name AS (SELECT...) SELECT ...`. I tested the code and it gave the same results as your original code.